# Compact sets in the Bochner space $L^{\infty}([0,T],H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I recently came across the following characterization of compact sets in $L^{\infty}([0,T],\mathbb{R})$:

"A closed, bounded subset $B$ of $L^{\infty}([0,T],\mathbb{R})$ is compact if and only if for each positive $\epsilon$ there is a finite partition  $(A_i)$ of $\Omega$ into disjoint, measurable sets so that the variation of each $f$ in $B$ is less than  $\epsilon$ (i.e., $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon$ a.e. on each $A_i$)."

I was wondering whether this result can be generalized to the Bochner space $L^{\infty}([0,T],H)$, where $H$ is a separable Hilbert space.

Comment: $\Omega=[0,T]$?

Comment: Yes. So this is the Bochner space of equivalence classes of essentially bounded $H$-valued functions $f: [0,T] \rightarrow H$.

Comment: Certainly not as is because the set of constant functions with norm $\leq 1$ is not compact.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that direction. I would also be interested in the converse, that is, if you know that a subset $K$ of $L^{\infty}([0,T],H)$ is compact then do you have this property? I would even be interested in seeing the proof of the quoted condition in the $\mathbb{R}$-valued setting.

Comment: To answer my own question, I think that the converse also fails. Consider the set $K=\{f\}$ consisting of just one element of $L^{\infty}([0,T],H)$. Then $K$ is compact. If the condition were to hold, then we could approximate any bounded Hilbert valued function uniformly which is impossible as one can only have such an approximation to functions with a totally bounded range. The last claim is proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3919965/494772